# Non-blocking streaming of data between two Quarkus services (Vert.x with Mutiny in Java)

Tags: java, quarkus, event-stream, vert.x-webclient, mutiny

**Update!**

I have fixed minor bugs in the sample code after solving some of the problems that were irrelevant to the main question which is still about non-blocking streaming between services.

**Background info**:

I'm porting a Spring WebFlux service under Quarkus. The service runs long searches on multiple huge data sets and returns the partial results in a Flux (text/event-stream) as they become available.

**Problem**:

Right now I'm trying to use Mutiny Multi with Vert.x under Quarkus but cannot figure out how the consumer service could receive this stream without blocking.

In all examples the consumer is either a JS front end page or the producer's content type is application/json that seems to bluck until the Multi completes before sending it over in one JSON object (which makes no sense in my application).

**Questions**:

1. How to receive text/event-stream with the Mutiny-flavoured Vert.x WebClient?
2. If the problem would be that the WebClient is not able to receive continuous steams: What is the standard way to stream data between two Quarkus services?

**Here is a simplified example**

**Test entity**

```java
public class SearchResult implements Serializable {

    private String content;

    public SearchResult(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }


    //.. toString, getters and setters
    
}
```

**Producer 1. simple infinite stream -> hangs**

```java
@GET
@Path("/search")
@Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
@SseElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Multi<SearchResult> getResults() {
        return Multi.createFrom().ticks().every(Duration.ofSeconds(2)              .onItem().transform(n -> new SearchResult(n.toString()));
}
```

**Producer 2. with Vertx Paths infinite stream -> hangs**

```java
@Route(path = "/routed", methods = HttpMethod.GET)
public Multi<SearchResult> getSrStreamRouted(RoutingContext context) {
        log.info("routed run");
        return ReactiveRoutes.asEventStream(Multi.createFrom().ticks().every(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                .onItem().transform(n -> new SearchResult(n.toString()));
}
```

**Producer 3. simple finite stream -> blocks until completion**

```java
@GET
@Path("/search")
@Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
@SseElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Multi<SearchResult> getResults() {
    return Multi.createFrom().ticks().every(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .transform().byTakingFirstItems(5)
        .onItem().transform(n -> new SearchResult(n.toString()));
}
```

**Consumer**:

Tried multiple different solutions on both producer and consumer sides, but **in every case the the stream blocks until it is complete** or hangs indefinitely without transferring data for infinite streams. I get the same results with httpie. Here is the latest iteration:

```java
WebClientOptions webClientOptions = new WebClientOptions().setDefaultHost("localhost").setDefaultPort(8182);
WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx, webClientOptions);
        
client.get("/string")
                .send()
                .onFailure().invoke(resp -> log.error("error: " + resp))
                .onItem().invoke(resp -> log.info("result: " + resp.statusCode()))
                .toMulti()
                .subscribe().with(r -> log.info(String.format("Subscribe: code:%d body:%s",r.statusCode(), r.bodyAsString())));
```

Comment: How do you see it's blocking? From the code I see, it will stream the 5 first items to the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vert.x Web Client does not work with SSE (Without configuration).
From https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/:

> Responses are fully buffered, use BodyCodec.pipe to pipe the response to a write stream

It waits until the response completes. You can either use the *raw* Vert.x HTTP Client or use the `pipe` codec. Examples are given on https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/#_decoding_responses.

Alternatively, you can use an SSE client such as in:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/master/kafka-quickstart/src/test/java/org/acme/kafka/PriceResourceTest.java#L27-L34

Comment: Appreciate the quick response Clement!
Out of curiosity:  So If I understand correctly, the "blocking" that I experience is not the result of the producer holding back on the stream elements until the stream is completed, but it's actually being buffered on the consumer side (for both the WebClient and httpie)?

Comment: Exactly. For httpie, you need to use `--stream`